# tweak old delphi exe to work with Win7 (windows size issue)

Tags: delphi, windows-7

How to tweak old legacy delphi exe to work well in Win7, there are no source codes, but luckily just one small GUI issue:

The main window size is fixed to be too narrow and now the text in control does not fit to screen. adjusting compatibility settings do not help at all.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that the application is configured for standard font size and you are using a larger font size. A screen shot would be helpful.
Anyway, usually the window size is in a resource in the application but it depends how the application has been written. You could use a resource tool to change the resource in the exe file directly (not easy to find exactly which form it is).
If you have the source code, the application can be edited and recompiled...

Answer (score 3):

A good resource editor which works with older Delphi applications is [Resource hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/).  I believe it has a few issues with forms which use frames, but other than that it is worth a try.  You should be able to export the DFM from the executable, adjust the size, and the replace the old with the new using this utility.

Comment: good tip, but reshacker crashes when viewing the app main form...

Comment: I was able to save rcdata.bin file, but opening it with delphi fails when renaming it to .DFM

Comment: Do you know what version of Delphi it was compiled with? It should be a text document so you should be able to open it with notepad.  If not, then you can run convert against it to convert the DFM to TXT.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly the form uses system default fonts, but on Windows Vista/7 they seem to be larger than on XP. As the designer of the application seems to have adjusted the size of the form to just fit the controls for XP default font size, I guess you'll have no other option but

1. try to get access to the source code
2. try to change the system's default font to what was used on XP